# Accessing Global Definitions of SAP smartforms within Program

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

I would like to access the value of variables defined in Global Definitions of a smartform within my ABAP program. Does anyone know how it would be possible?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid SO question, no need to close it.

Answer (score 1):

In short: You don't - not directly. Use interface parameters to pass values into the form (NEVER deliberately do anything in the form that would require you to pass staff back out), and in the form, either use the interface input parameters directly or, in the initialization coding of the form, transfer the values from the input parameters to the global variables. While it would be technically possible to access the values, there's nothing to be gained by it - and **a lot** of maintainability to be lost.